# Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'; phpinfo shows no PDO extensions, but php -i (php -m) do

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework

I'm learning the Zend framework, going through the Album example.

When I open the browser to access the Album module, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'

After A LOT of googling and stackoverflowing, it seems that the PDOs are not active.

What really bugs me is that when I use 'php -i' from command line, I do see PDOs enabled. But phpinfo() shows no PDOs.

I tried a couple of things already. They didn't work:

1. Setting the absolute path to 'extension_dir'.
2. Adding path to the php folder to the 'path' environmental variable.
3. Remove php + apache, install again.
4. Of course, uncomment extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll.

Please help!

Comment: php -i is command line php. you're probably running phpinfo() in a web context, which can have ENTIRELY different .ini file options. check the info output - one of the sections buried in there tells you exactly which .ini file(s) were parsed at startup.

Comment: @MarcB, i think you're right. only problem is that in the phpinfo() output it says c:\windows, but there's no php.ini there. how could this be? (puzzled)

Comment: php.ini is merely overrides for php's compiled-in defaults. having a .ini isn't necessary - php will just use its internal defaults.

Comment: @MarcB, you were right. i added the PHPINIDir directive into the virtual hosts file of apache and it worked. if you wish, put up an answer. i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark B. He suggested the right answer in the comments.

The .php file with phpinfo() in the browser shows that php loaded php.ini from C:\Windows, but there is no php.ini under my C:\Windows. The reason why it's like this is that php.ini overrides php's compiled-in defaults. So I saw the compiled-in defaults with phpinfo().

I used the PHPIniDir in my virtual host to point to the actual folder with the php.ini file. Then I saw the PDO extensions, and everything works fine.

PS: Marc, if you post your answer, I'll remove mine and accept yours.